# Spark memory implications for using the case class copy method on dataframe fields

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, apache-spark-sql, case-class

I am trying to fix a memory issue in a spark job and there is part of the spark job that uses a case class object that contains a field that is a large Spark Dataframe object.  Later on in the Spark job another large dataframe is computed and replaces the dataframe in the case class using the case classes `.copy()` method i.e. something like

```
    case class Example(id: Int, bigDf: Dataframe)
    
    val thisExample = Example(id, originalDf)
    val newDF = ...
    val newExample = thisExample.copy(bigDF = newDF)
```

And this dataframe field updating actually happens several more times.  I am wondering if all this copying is causing unnecessary memory overhead.  Would it be more efficient if `Example` was an actual class rather than a case class and the `bigDF` field could be set without having to use `.copy()`?  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, that means creating a new Example object every time... on the other hand, Scala, under the hood, creates myriads of small objects all the time (it is the only way of implement a functional language on top of the JVM), so the contribution from your code is probably going to be negligible.